# Where has the elections site gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, offline, election-page

The http://elections.stackexchange.com/ site with meta data about SE elections seems to be offline. In the event that this is a location change, the links from active election pages on the network should be updated with it's new URL. In the event unicorns have absconded with the servers, they should be reprimanded and not given cookies until they return the goods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* it responds poorly to the API going offline, which has happened a bit over the last week or so due to the data center moves. It should automatically restart anyway in that case, but sometimes that seems to not work.

I'll try to get it to handle the API being unreachable more gracefully, but in the meantime I've gone ahead and restarted it (…which I actually meant to do after noticing this earlier in the day). Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: It's gone, again. But this time I think it has been gone for a while now. What happened?